# Which formula could I use to increase the vertical exaggeration of a pointcloud?

Tags: point-cloud

I have a pointcloud of a very flat area! I would like to exaggerate the Z values in the same way software visualisations do - e.g ArcScene

My method would be to create a raster DEM from the Pointcloud and then use the Raster calculator to use the formula but am not sure how? Would it be some sort of exponential/logorithmic formula?

Comment: just times it by a number that makes it stick out, no need to over complicate. that is what arcscene does i think

Comment: x^y to your liking.

Comment: Zmin +(z-Zmin)*n, try different n

Comment: What is the thinking behind your formula?